# radio button value is not inserted

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert values in an edit form page  using 2 radio buttons. When a specific radio button is selected, user needs to enter a date and it'll be inserted into database. This part works fine, however when I choose the first radio button (FULL SUPPLY), the value is not inserted in the database. Here's the code that I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate() {
        if ((document.getElementById('choiceText').checked)
            && (document.getElementById('othertext').value == '')) { 
            alert('Response required'); 
            return false; 
        }
        else { 
            return true; 
        }
    }
</script>

<input name="pendaftaran_tca" type="radio" value="FULL SUPPLY" />FULL    SUPPLY<br />
<input name="pendaftaran_tca" id="choiceText" type="radio"  />TCA
<input type="date" name="pendaftaran_tca" id="othertext" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input name="pendaftaran_tca" type="radio" id="choiceText" value="FULL SUPPLY" />`

`id="choiceText"`

you didn't put the id of the radio that's why it's not returning any value.

if this help you please return to me thanks

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help! I've put the radio id but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you put already a value for the date? because your if function means that you should put a value on to your date and also to your radio button,

Comment: have you tried this 

`function check() {
    document.getElementById("choiceText").checked = true;
}`

Comment: i mean you put false if you're checking with a null value.